# How to iterate a select statement over a range of days

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to iterate a select statement over a range of days.  The purpose is to get the volume of open records in our various groups at a moment in time each day in the past year, by using the open and close time stamps of the records.  The select statement is something like this:

```
select I.INC_GROUP, count(I.INC_GROUP) as INC_VOLUME
from XXX.INCIDENT i
where
I.OPEN_TIME < to_date('2015/09/21 08:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') and
I.CLOSE_TIME > to_date('2015/09/21 08:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
group by I.INC_GROUP
```

I am trying to iterate it for 8AM today-366 to 8AM today-1.  My output would be inserted into a table and would consist of the INC_GROUP, INC_VOLUME, and the date of the iteration (first record would be 22-SEP-14 08:00:00).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CONNECT BY` to generate a set of numbers and use these in conjunction with date logic (DATE + 1 will add a day). This will generate you a row for each day.

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE - LEVEL) + (1/24*8)
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365
```

This can then be incorporated to another data set, for example:

```
WITH days AS (
  SELECT
    TRUNC(SYSDATE - LEVEL) + (1/24*8) day_start
  -- This adds a day to the above and removes a second
  , TRUNC(SYSDATE - LEVEL + 1) + (1/24*8) - (1/24/60/60) day_end    
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365
)
SELECT 
  days.day_start
, COUNT(yt.date_col) num
FROM days
LEFT JOIN your_table yt ON yt.date_col BETWEEN days.day_start AND days.day_end
```

This would give you a row for each day and a number of matching rows from `your_table` that fell between 8am and 7:59:59 the following day.

Comment: Thanks I will try to adapt that to what I need.  Records look like this :
`inc_group, open_time, close_time
abc, 2015-07-13 09:13:37, 2015-07-14 03:13:37
def, 2015-05-13 10:33:23, 2015-05-18 11:13:43`
So the logic in the second portion won't work.  The date from the first portion (dt) would need to be a variable somehow, inserted into the select statement example i gave in place of the two to_date portions.

Comment: Got it working, thank you.
`SELECT INC_GROUP, DT, COUNT(INC_GROUP)
FROM(
    WITH DAYS AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - LEVEL, 'YYYY/MM/DD') || ' 08:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') dt
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365)
    SELECT I.INC_GROUP, DAYS.DT
    FROM XXX.INCIDENT i INNER JOIN DAYS ON 
    I.OPEN_TIME < DAYS.dt and
    I.CLOSE_TIME > DAYS.dt
)
GROUP BY DT, INC_GROUP`